# Animation positions and animate along the path - Animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

two questions here.

The first: I placed objects in certain positions and would like to introduce new vector positions that would become starting point for these objects and animate them so their last position will be this one. Here's the screenshot:

[image: an]

And the second one: I got objects placed on the spline using the loop, but i'm having trouble understanding how to animate them along the spline (like with Follow Path constraint).

Guys, thank you in advance.

Comment: I see your questions on animation nodes. Would you be interested in joining Blender Maths group in Facebook? This group encourages interest in Animation Nodes and Sverchok Nodes and scripts with maths.

Answer (score 3):

### For the first question:

It seems you need the Object ID Key feature to store the initial transformation info for the objects. Here is how to use the Object ID Key node:

[image]

IMHO, the whole nodetree could be optimized like this:

[image]

---

### For the second question:

A basic example setup would be:

[image]
[image]

BTW, there is a nice template called *Distribute Instances on Spline*, which is a great start to learn how to make things working like this. You can find it in **Templates** menu on Node Editor's header.