# How can I select object from collection and place it on spline from different collection THEN do it again until all splines are used?

Tags: animation-nodes, collections, instances

This is [follow up to my previous question here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227192/how-can-i-move-lots-of-objects-on-path-and-control-it-somehow). I managed to get an answer and improve on it, however my current implementation is pretty cumbersome.

I need to simplify my current solution, as Animation Nodes take about 500ms+ to run the whole thing.

**My question is, is it possible to select random object from collection, then place it on a spline from different collection - rinse and repeat until all splines are covered?**

I already have a solution on placing objects on splines. But now I have 39 splines, and I have 39 "groups of nodes" and it is getting really slow. I feel like there is a Loop solution to this, but I can't figure it out.

Here is how my project looks like now:

[image: Solid render view]

Lots of instanced 3D icons "marching" towards buildings. It works pretty good. However, my current Animation Nodes set up looks like this.

[image: AN nodes set up]

It is difficult to navigate. I have 5 different icons and 39 splines. I tried to use Loop and Groups to help simplify certain steps. But I can't figure out how to make it more simple.

**Here are node groups:**

This one places objects on a spline and orients them towards spline direction - Marching Ants Set Up.
[image: Place objects on spline]

This one controls spacing between different objects on each spline - gaps between icons.

[image: Icon Gaps control]

This one does all the animation using time. I want to vary speed of various "marching icons", so I put it in a Group.

[image: Icon Animation Control]

## Here are the groups I couldn't figure out how to connect together in 1 loop, with incrementation till all Splines are used.

Spline selection from Collection.

[image: Spline Selection]

Icon Selection from collection and scale control.

[image: Icon Selection from Collection]

**And here is how they come together.**

I select different Icon with Index, change scale, run it through Instancer and feed it into Loop to place them all on a Spline. Other Groups are plugged in as well at this stage.

Float Input node is used to pick starting Index from Spline Collection, then I add 1 to it with each duplication.

[image: Main Set Up]

And then I simply copy and paste main node set up to repeat the whole process and add "1" to Spline Collection Index.

[image: Set Up]

It was fine to use the whole "Place Objects on Spline" Loop set up at the beginning, but now I have 39 splines. I had to duplicate the groups many times and now it is getting difficult to navigate and even run.

[Here is a Blend file on GoFile website](https://gofile.io/d/NAvWrA), if you want to poke around - I'm not sure how long it will be available online as service is free.

Comment: link doesn't work. Please use https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to partially solve it by trail and error. I tried uploading final file to Blend Exchange, but I'm hitting file upload limits. Currently, mu blend file is at 60MB+. [I have uploaded it here to my Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LqSuW8-9lrEUDymBL2q_olECUMWh77vF/view?usp=sharing) if you would like to check it out. I will keep the link live for next few months.

**In the mean time, here is my partial solution with Animation Nodes:**

This node set up, selects all the icons / objects from a collection. Then places them on a spline from another collection. I set it up in a way that I can control duration of objects floating on splines from start to end and distance between them.

**Nodes in Green** are the ones, where you select your objects / splines collections and modify number of final objects etc.

[image: Icon Placement on Spline]

And here is node set up, where animation happens on spline

[image: Animate on spline]

The above set up works ok, but problem is if you have a large number of splines. I had to duplicate 2nd node set up 9 times, since I had 9 splines.

I couldn't figure out some sort Loop Subprogram, that would grab Icons from Collection and assign them one by one on each spline randomly, and make X amount of instances of those icons.

I managed to do something semi-close to it, when I was building this project, but objects (icons) were clipping through each other, distancing between them was not working, and they were traveling the splines one at a time. Not in a swarm way.

**Here is how the whole thing turned out in final render.**

[image: Main view]

[image: Close up]

[image: Top view]

[image: Final swarm]